# Does facebook icons and buttons are under copyrights?

Tags: facebook, copyright-display

I like to use some facebook buttons and icons, like these

[image]

[image]

Is it ok to use? On their [brand permission center](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php), icons and that buttons are not indicated. And I can't find article regarding this matter.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

All icons and images will be copyrighted to Facebook, so you should ask for permission before use. As a precaution, it's best to contact Facebook regarding the use of images / icons not covered by the Brand Permission Center.